# почему 2 раза выводится строка

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

```
org 100h
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, stringd
int 21h
stringd db "hell$"
ret
```

почему этот код выводит строку "hell" два раза вместо положеных одного, ассемблер FASM

Comment: Да вообще непонятно, почему оно не виснет, пытаясь выполнить текст строки как исполняемый код... `ret` должно быть сразу после `int 21h`.

Comment: благодарю, я поставил `ret` сразу после `int` и уже нормально выводит!